# How to enable scroll bar in ABAP Table View?

Tags: abap

I am trying to fill a table using an internal table. Table is being filled perfectly but I can  see the first something rows of the table, the rest is not seen because there is no scroll bar.

Anyone who knows to enable it ?

Comment: Could you please describe how you display the table in detail? There are at least four ways to display a table...

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way where you can enable the scroll bar in a table by using the table controls.I would like to share a link from SAP help which demonstrates this.
[Table Controls:Scrolling](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/9f/dbac4435c111d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.